# Format a specific GeoJSON file into the correct format

Tags: geojson, json

I want to use this [json file](https://github.com/RitterLean/Geojson) it is no GeoJSON file yet but I noticed that it contains several Features and not one which I find confusing. I wanted to ask if you know some tool where I can merge all Features/FeatureCollections into one valid GeoJSON file so I can use it for like D3.js? The original file is [here](http://data.information.dk/isil/data/isil.en.json) and I already got rid of the stuff which is not needed for the geojson.

Here is an excerpt of the GeoJson, it is fairly big so I'ts just a snippet

```
{"points": [{
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [41.9773865, 36.3372536],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 1,
                "location": "Sinjar",
                "date": "2015-10-16"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [43.4873886, 34.9301605],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 2,
                "location": "Baiji",
                "date": "2015-10-16"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [42.4509315, 36.3707008],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 3,
                "location": "Tal Afar",
                "date": "2015-10-16"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [43.76667, 35.31667],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 1,
                "location": "Hawija",
                "date": "2015-10-16"
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [43.7820587, 33.3516083],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 4,
                "location": "Fallujah",
                "date": "2015-04-24"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [43.2637405, 33.4324112],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 1,
                "location": "Ramadi",
                "date": "2015-04-24"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [43.1170998, 36.3246002],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 5,
                "location": "Mosul",
                "date": "2015-04-24"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [38.3535004, 36.8908997],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 4,
                "location": "Kobane",
                "date": "2015-04-24"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [42.4509315, 36.3707008],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 1,
                "location": "Tal Afar",
                "date": "2015-04-24"
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [43.7820587, 33.3516083],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 1,
                "location": "Fallujah",
                "date": "2015-09-09"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [43.2637405, 33.4324112],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 3,
                "location": "Ramadi",
                "date": "2015-09-09"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [41.9773865, 36.3372536],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 1,
                "location": "Sinjar",
                "date": "2015-09-09"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [43.4873886, 34.9301605],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 1,
                "location": "Baiji",
                "date": "2015-09-09"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [42.4509315, 36.3707008],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "properties": {
                "attacks": 2,
                "location": "Tal Afar",
                "date": "2015-09-09"
            }
        },
```

Do you have some ideas how to solve this problem and get a proper GeoJSON file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write a simple script in (for example) Python that will process the data for you.

```
import json
from itertools import chain
```

Open the file and read the data into a Python dictionary:

```
isil = json.load(open('isil.en.json'))
```

The points object is just a list of feature collections, so you can use the python `itertools` library to help chain the features in those collections together:

```
features = list(chain.from_iterable(fc['feature'] for fc in isil['points']))
```

And finally write a new feature collection with all 2818 features out to a file.

```
feature_collection = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection":,
    "features": features
}

with open("isil_points.geojson", "w") as f:
    json.dump(feature_collection, f)
```

And that should be able to be loaded up into a system of your choice. Looking at the data You'll probably have to do some manual cleaning as well (some "total" locations and a few points that don't have a location), but that should be a start.

[image: The points from each of the feature collections, merged.]

Answer (score 7):

Because it's a "oneshot", you can do it manually (also possible running via Node)

Open a JavaScript console in your browser.

You need to loop to get an array of array of `Feature` (because each `FeatureCollection` have one or more `Feature`)

Then, you will use the flatten function to transform the array of array into an array (a recursive function borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15030117)

The full code is below (except the file content, not complete to keep things readable)

```
// Copy/paste the text from you source https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RitterLean/Geojson/master/geofile.json 
content = {
"points": [{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [41.9773865, 36.3372536],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "properties": {
            "attacks": 1,
            "location": "Sinjar",
            "date": "2015-10-16"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [43.4873886, 34.9301605],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "properties": {
            "attacks": 2,
            "location": "Baiji",
            "date": "2015-10-16"
        }
    }, {
    ...
    // Be careful, incomplete because shortened for illustration 

intermediate_result = content['points'].map(function(el){
    return el.features;
});

function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
    return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
  }, []);
};

geojson_output = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": flatten(intermediate_result)
}
// Transform the object to a string you can paste into a file
console.log(JSON.stringify(geojson_output));
```

The result can be seen at http://geojson.io/#id=gist:anonymous/da10ab9afc9a5941ba66&map=4/19.48/22.32

You will see that some results have wrong coordinates (0, 0). It's due to the original content.

From this demo, you can also export to GeoJSON.